# What makes certain obligate anaerobes viable in fermentation starter cultures?

Tags: physiology, bacteriology, food, taxonomy, microarray

If Propionibacterium are obligate anaerobes (to wit, poisoned by oxygen), what makes 'Dairy' or classical propionibacteria (e.g. P. shermanii, P. jensenii, P. acidicpropionici, et al) viable in Fermentation starter cultures?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact that they are obligate anaerobes?

Comment: they are not obligate anaerobes..

Comment: @AlanBoyd [Obligate anaerobe on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obligate_anaerobe#Examples)

Comment: @WYSIWYG What are they?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Here's a quote from [this](http://bit.ly/1rNqWzc) source: "Their [Propionibacteria] exact atmospheric requirements remain a matter of controversy, and they are often described as obligate anaerobes."

Comment: http://mic.sgmjournals.org/content/127/1/121.full.pdf
 - link to a paper in which P. shermanii is grown in flask culture. Although the conditions are clearly designed to achieve low oxygen concentrations in the culture, they also indicate that oxygen is not toxic for this organism. This is from the WP page you linked to: "Obligate anaerobes are microorganisms that are killed by normal atmospheric concentrations of oxygen (21% O2). Oxygen tolerance varies between species, some capable of surviving in up to 8% oxygen, others losing viability unless the oxygen concentration is less than 0.5%."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (mic.sgmjournals.org/content/127/1/121.full.pdf) is a link to a paper in which *P. shermanii* is grown in flask culture. Although the conditions are clearly designed to achieve low oxygen concentrations in the culture (the flask is almost full and is only shaken occasionally), they also indicate that oxygen is not toxic for this organism.

Also, this is from the WP page you linked to:

> Obligate anaerobes are microorganisms that are killed by normal atmospheric concentrations of oxygen (21% O<sub>2</sub>). Oxygen tolerance varies between species, some capable of surviving in up to 8% oxygen, others losing viability unless the oxygen concentration is less than 0.5%.